# Volume keys not working after installing Silverlight

Tags: macos, audio, silverlight

I downloaded Silverlight for Safari to use Netflix.

This download has caused my MacBook's volume keys to become non-functional, although I can still change volume through the icon in the menu bar or through system preferences. When I press the keys to change the volume, the transparent volume icon appears on the screen with a circle-slash icon at bottom center.

Does anyone know how to make the keys functional again? I deleted Silverlight but still no sound.

Comment: What version of OS X? How did you delete Silverlight, exactly? Have you rebooted since?

Comment: OS X 10.7.5   To delete Silverlight I went to finder, opened new finder window, typed in Silverlight into the search box, dragged all files with that name to trash and them deleted trash.  I then restarted my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a … piece of software that doesn't provide you with a dedicated uninstaller and leaves all kinds of files on your hard drive. Searching for "Silverlight" with Finder and deleting what you found will most certainly not remove all traces of it.

Open Finder, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Now,  paste the following:

```
/private/var/db/receipts/
```

Delete anything you can find starting with `com.microsoft.silverlight` or `com.microsoft.installSilverLight`. You will be prompted for your password. Deleting these should get rid of the installer receipts.

Now let's try and delete the plugins themselves. Again, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and enter:

```
/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/
```

Delete the Silverlight folder from here. Again, let's go to another folder:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

Here, remove `WPFe` and `Silverlight` if they're still there. I'd reboot after that, just to be sure.

Comment: did all that and still nothing.   But I read another website and it said that if you plug headphones in, then unplug them then it would solve the problem.  I did that and now the sound is back.  Don't understand why because I haven't used headphones on my mac in months.  thanks for all your help.

Comment: @terry: Sounds like you accidentally pressed the *Mute* combination on your keyboard, and the system remembered that until you plugged in headphones.  Silverlight is probably not related at all.